# PyInstaller: Can't find .so module when exe is executed

Tags: python, pyinstaller, .so

A python script uses a .so file. 
I made an exe for this python script using PyInstaller.

But when I execute the generated exe, it is unable to locate this .so file
So how to link this .so to a python code that will get converted to a .exe

Note: when running the .py program, if I set the location of .so in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it executes the program correctly but once I make the exe using
pyinstaller script.py --onefile
(with .so in the same directory), it doesnt find the .so file..

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your . so file is in your system library path as well as your python library path. Setting your LD path is a quick fix. PyInstaller will need it in your system path. Depending on your Windows version it's Environment variables>PATH.